# No rule to make target `NOTICE-TARGET-STATIC_LIBRARIES-lib_driver_cmd_bcmdhd while building boot2gecko

Tags: android

While building boot2gecko for d2att, I get

```
target Strip: libssl (out/target/product/d2att/obj/lib/libssl.so)
make: *** No rule to make target 
     `NOTICE-TARGET-STATIC_LIBRARIES-lib_driver_cmd_bcmdhd',

 needed by `out/target/product/d2att/system/bin/wpa_supplicant'. 
         Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have recieved errors that

```
out/target/product/d2att/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/
lib_driver_cmd_bcmdhd_intermediates/lib_driver_cmd_bcmdhd.a 
does not exit,
```

so I built cm9 and copied the files in that folder over.

How can I fix this?

Also, how can I use a prebuilt wpa_supplicant instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a compiled wpa_supplicant  and change the module make file for wpa_supplicant to use `$(BUILD_PREBUILT)` and specify the binary for the wpa_supplicant. That should avoid the issue. You should only need to tweak the place where the module is defined in the build system to get this to work.